# Formula to calculate the next coordinate given a coordinate, distance,direction and probably speed

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, mapping

I have this coordinates `52.3545362,4.7638767` which I got from a Google Maps search of Amsterdam.

URL

`https://www.google.com/maps/place/Amsterdam,+Netherlands/@52.3545362,4.7638767,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c63fb5949a7755:0x6600fd4cb7c0af8d!8m2!3d52.3666969!4d4.8945398`

Is there a formula I can use to get the coordinates if I were to move one meter from my current coordinates in any direction for instance,

What would be the new coordinates if I moved 1 meter westwards from the coordinate `52.3545362,4.7638767`

If there is a way I can do this along known routes, it would be an added bonus.

Comment: That's more of a cartesian plane if i am not wrong. Does what she is showing apply in a radar if i wanted to calculate probable next point

Comment: There are many ways, for example: Turf.js library https://turfjs.org/, online sites like http://geo.javawa.nl/coordcalc/index_en.html, doing your own calculation with formulas http://www.geomidpoint.com/destination/calculation.html

Comment: Awesome. I shall have a look. I wish turfjs could be a py implementation.

Comment: One meter is a tiny distance, only 0.9e-05 degrees to the north or south, and probably not more than 2.5e-05 east/west. The formal name to your task is the Forward (or Direct) Problem of Geodesy. Velocity is not part of the problem, only lat, lon, bearing, and distance.

Comment: Thanks @Vince  the Forward (or Direct) Problem of Geodesy is new term. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I found a Python library that does what I want

```
def destination(point, distance, bearing):
```

https://pypi.org/project/geo-py/

but as for now it doesnt have asynio support.

For a plain Python function adapted from here http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

```
R = ... Radius of earth ...
def great_circle_destination(lon1, lat1, bearing, dist):
    lat2 = math.asin( math.sin(lat1)*math.cos(dist/R) + 
          math.cos(lat1)*math.sin(dist/R)*math.cos(bearing) )
    lon2 = lon1 + math.atan2(math.sin(bearing)*math.sin(dist/R)*math.cos(lat1), 
                 math.cos(dist/R)-math.sin(lat1)*math.sin(lat2)
    return lon2, lat2
```

Thanks to Ryan: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580414/great-circle-destination-formula-for-python